# how to overcome problem in integer overflow even using long also wrong answers?

Tags: java, arrays

for input 2:100000,90000 getting wrong answer even i used long

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = s.nextInt();

        int arr[] = new int[a];

        for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
            arr[i] = s.nextInt();

        Arrays.sort(arr);

        long sum=0;

        sum=(arr[a-1])*(arr[a-2]); 

        System.out.println(sum);

    }
}
```

how to overcome problem in integer overflow even using long also wrong answers ?

Comment: The answer is 9 billion, which not out of range of a `long`.  Something else is up.

Comment: Did you try using BigInteger or BigDecimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sum=(arr[a-1])*(arr[a-2]);
```

This multiples an **int** by an **int** and then assigns the **int** result (which may have overflowed) to a **long** variable.

To use **long** arithmetic, write

```
sum = (long) arr[a-1] * (long) arr[a-2];
```

You don't need both casts, but is seems a lttle clearer with them.